# C# Read text file that is fully locked or read output outside if statement

Tags: c#, c++

This question has been asked a lot of times but i am not sure if i did find the right answer which would be "It's not possible". Every time i hear something isn't possible i'm not sure if it's true. I mean somehow there got to be a solution.

So here is my thing. I am working on a C# application which at some point should read a .txt file to use in my code. The problem is that a C++ file writes to this file constantly. I do not have the source of this project.

As my understanding there are a few ways to read a file even if it's locked. The problem is i tried them all. ( using ReadWrite, Read, Write, Delete etc. ). Nothing seemed to succeed. It looks like the file is locked by all means.

So my question again, is it really possible that there is no way to read a text file if it is fully locked by a other application where i do not have the source from? Is there no way around?

If not there is the following. The application itself prints the exact same info i want to read out of the txt file. So i figured why not reading it from the application directly. The problem is though that i am not sure how to do that outside of a "if" statement.

**For example my code is:**

```
if (wname.Length )
{

    Process compiler = new Process();
    compiler.StartInfo.FileName = fn;
    compiler.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wd;
    compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    compiler.Start();

}
```

**What i would like to do later on is:**

```
string result = compiler.StartInfo.ReadToEnd();
```

Never the less this is not possible because "The name 'compiler' does not exist in the current context".

Losing the IF statement is not a possibility. Any solution to that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create the `compiler` object outside the scope of the if.

Comment: Also - it appears you have two different questions here - one - specifically about the error you got and the second about how to read that other file..

Answer (score 2):

"is it really possible that there is no way to read a text file if it is fully locked by a other application" - depends on the Operating System and File System in use. You don't tell us what you are using so how can we answer? Some systems use kernel-enforced mandatory file locks, some only use advisory locks, some can use both.

In any case, you ask if it "is possible" - well, in the extreme case; if you bypass the operating system and manipulate the raw data on disk directly, then of course it is *possible* - hard; sure, but possible.
If you want to stay within the nice world of the OS, then it depends (as mentioned above) on the OS and file system and the type of file locks used.

Answer (score 1):

`compiler` is defined in the scope of the `if (wname.Length)` statement. 
Your line with the error appears outside of that scope and thus you get that compilation error.

Define the `compiler` outside or the if statement and then you will have it in the scope of the other line. However if you do not initialize it outside of the if statement then you need to check that it is not null before using otherwise you will get a `NullReferenceException`

More to read about [scopes in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)